# How to make npm not to get the latest dependency of dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

I use a node module A that is dependent on node module B. The node module A is dependent on B with version higher than 2.0.1. However, there is version 2.0.5, that is the latest version. The version 2.0.5 is not working well with my program, I would like to get the specific version 2.0.1 and not 2.0.5. When I do npm install I get the 2.0.5 version. Is there any way that I can make npm install get the lowest suitable version of a package and not the highest?

edit: I used [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/) instead of npm and it did exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the `package.json` file of dependency A in your `node_modules` folder and make sure it specifies that dependency B is version 2.0.1.

After this run `npm update`

Comment: I know I can do it that way, but the next time I will do npm install on my whole project ( when I will take a new clone from the git repository ) I will get the 2.0.5 version again. I wonder if there is a solution without modifying the package.json of other projects.

Comment: You could try adding this specific dependency to your repo (still make sure you .gitignore the rest of the node_modules folder) that way you always get the same version of this specific dependency, even when you clone into a new location and do `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a nice way to do that. You can run `npm shrinkwrap` in your project folder and then go to `npm-shrinkwrap.json` and search for package `B` and change it's version to `2.0.1`. 
What `npm shrinkwrap` does is lock down the dependency versions, so, whenever you update other packages, and still have the same problem with package `A` and `B`, you will need to run `npm shrinkwrap` again. 
When package `B` fix the problem with version `2.0.5` you can delete `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap